# How correct return reference to object from iterator in c++

Tags: c++, vector, reference, iterator, visual-c++-2010

I have a troubles with using references to elements of `std::vector` in such code:

```
class CurrencyList {
public:
    Currency &append(wstring name);
private:
    vector<Currency> mCurrencyList;
};
Currency &CurrencyList::append(wstring name){
    vector<Currency>::iterator currency = findByName(name);
    if(currency != mCurrencyList.end()) 
        return *currency;
    mCurrencyList.push_back(Currency(name));
    return *mCurrencyList.rbegin();
}
```

It used in this code:

```
Currency& BaseVal = currencyList.append("AAA");
Currency& ProfitVal = currencyList.append("BBB");
return new CurrencyPair(name, BaseVal, ProfitVal);
```

When I recieve ProfitVal on second line, value of BaseVal is damaged. I think that return *mCurrencyList.rbegin(); give me refference to iterator, not to element of vector. And then it changing in second call the first value was changed. How I must use iterator and references in this situation?

Comment: A reference to the iterator wouldn't compile when you have a return type of `Currency&`.

Comment: from cplusplus.com: If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.
Otherwise, only the end iterator is invalidated, and all iterators, pointers and references to elements are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

Comment: You should pass `name` by constant reference:  `Currency& append(const wstring& name);`.

Comment: @chris All compile correct. This sample of code from good compiling project

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I add const and it work the same: value of `BaseVal` was damaged after recieving `ProfitVal`

Comment: @NathanOliver May be my vector reallocated when I add second value to it. But how I can get right reference to first element in this situation?

Comment: The `const` is a safety measure for the compiler. By passing by `const` reference, the compiler doesn't copy the `name` variable when calling the method; it accessing the variable directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest solution is to return a *copy* of the `Currency`:

```
Currency append(const wstring& name)  // Note the return type.
{
    vector<Currency>::iterator currency = findByName(name);
    if(currency != mCurrencyList.end()) 
        return *currency;
    mCurrencyList.push_back(Currency(name));
    return *mCurrencyList.rbegin();
}
```

Note that the reference symbol, `&`, has been removed from the function signature.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your help. But in this situation I prefer to change vector of elements to vector of pointers on elements `vector<Currency *>` and manualli allocate memory for it. I think it will be more right solution in this situation.